# Oracle Syntax & Selecting Max and Min Rows in Reflexive Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm struggling with a database situation involving reflexive relations and Oracle syntax. The best analogy I can come up with for my current problem is:

Relationships Table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|    PERSON1   |    PERSON2   |    STARTED    |   ENDED    |
------------------------------------------------------------
| Some Guy     | Some Lady    |     1998      |    2000    |
| Some Lady    | Some Guy     |     1998      |    2000    |
|     ....     |     ....     |     ....      |     ....   |
|     ....     |     ....     |     ....      |     ....   |
|     ....     |     ....     |     ....      |     ....   |
|     ....     |     ....     |     ....      |     ....   |
| Another Guy  | Another Lady |     1992      |    2005    |
| Another Lady | Another Guy  |     1992      |    2005    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Query:

What I'm trying to select are both the oldest and the newest rows (W.R.T. "STARTED"). If this wasn't a reflexive relation, it would be easy to return:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|    PERSON1   |    PERSON2   |    STARTED    |   ENDED    |
------------------------------------------------------------
| Some Guy     | Some Lady    |     1998      |    2000    |
| Another Guy  | Another Lady |     1992      |    2005    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

From this:

```
SELECT PERSON1, PERSON2, STARTED, ENDED
FROM RELATIONSHIPS
WHERE (STARTED) IN
(
    SELECT MAX(STARTED) AS START_YEAR FROM RELATIONSHIPS
    UNION 
    SELECT MIN(STARTED) AS START_YEAR FROM RELATIONSHIPS
);
```

This returns:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|    PERSON1   |    PERSON2   |    STARTED    |   ENDED    |
------------------------------------------------------------
| Some Guy     | Some Lady    |     1998      |    2000    |
| Another Guy  | Another Lady |     1992      |    2005    |
| Some Lady    | Some Guy     |     1998      |    2000    |
| Another Lady | Another Guy  |     1992      |    2005    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

... When I really only need the first two rows (order not guaranteed)

---

Had I not been using Oracle, I know I could have achieved something acceptable using (Unless someone also knows a better way):

```
SELECT PERSON1, PERSON2, STARTED, ENDED
FROM RELATIONSHIPS
ORDER BY STARTED DESC
LIMIT 1

UNION

SELECT PERSON1, PERSON2, STARTED, ENDED
FROM RELATIONSHIPS
ORDER BY STARTED ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I did that in hopes of maybe a straight SQL solution that would work agnostic of either

Comment: What is your expected output if you have another pair of people who have the same minimum `STARTED` value? Only return the first row with a minimum value (ignoring the second pair) or return one row from both pairs (and have two rows output with the minimum)?

Comment: MT0, not specified in requirements, so first result is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help. This was so simple I never realized it.

```
SELECT PERSON1, PERSON2, STARTED, ENDED
FROM RELATIONSHIPS
WHERE (STARTED) IN
(
    SELECT MAX(STARTED) FROM RELATIONSHIPS
    UNION 
    SELECT MIN(STARTED) FROM RELATIONSHIPS
)
AND PERSON1 < PERSON2;
```

The last line basically took care of it. Since a person won't be in a relationship with themselves, this forces the reflexive relations to only go one way.

Answer (score 1):

This will return only one maximum and one minimum row (analogous to your `UNION` of `LIMIT 1` queries):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (PERSON1, PERSON2, STARTED, ENDED) as
  SELECT 'Some Guy'     ,'Some Lady'   ,1998, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Some Lady'    ,'Some Guy'    ,1998, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Another Guy'  ,'Another Lady',1992, 2005 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Another Lady' ,'Another Guy' ,1992, 2005 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT person1, person2, started, ended
FROM   (
  SELECT r.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY started ASC )  AS rn_asc,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY started DESC ) AS rn_desc
  FROM   relationships r
)
WHERE  rn_asc = 1 OR rn_desc = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
PERSON1      PERSON2     STARTED ENDED
------------ ----------- ------- -----
Some Guy     Some Lady      1998  2000
Another Lady Another Guy    1998  2005
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but I found an even easier solution to handle the reflexive relation and cut half the table.

Answer (score 0):

I make next solution. I test it only on oracle database, but it should work with mysql too.

```
with RELATIONSHIPS(PERSON1,PERSON2,STARTED,ENDED) as (
select 'Some Guy','Some Lady', 1998, 2000 from dual union all
select 'Another Guy' ,'Another Lady',1992,2005 from dual union all
select 'Some Lady','Some Guy', 1998, 2000 from dual union all
select 'Another Lady','Another Guy' ,1992,2005 from dual)
select distinct 
       least(PERSON1,PERSON2) as PERSON1 ,
       greatest(PERSON1,PERSON2) as PERSON2,
       STARTED,
       ENDED
from RELATIONSHIPS r 
join (
    SELECT MAX(STARTED) AS START_YEAR FROM RELATIONSHIPS
    UNION 
    SELECT MIN(STARTED) AS START_YEAR FROM RELATIONSHIPS
) st on r.STARTED = START_YEAR
```